# What is the stabilizer of the following $7$-dimensional cross-product?

Tags: lie-groups, exceptional-groups

Upon visiting Prof. Nurowski's homepage (http://www.fuw.edu.pl/~nurowski/), at the top of the page, there is the following $7$-dimensional cross product:

$e_1 e_2 = e_4$, $e_2 e_3 = e_5$,...

and so on, proceeding cyclically modulo $7$. My question is as follows. What is the stabilizer of this cross-product in $GL(7,\mathbb{R})$? Is it the compact $G_2$ or some other real form of the $G_2^{\mathbb{C}}$? I thought this question could be fun to post, particularly since this cross-product is particularly easy to memorize (I think I know the answer though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a "trivial" question. There is an element $g$ in $GL(7,\mathbb{R})$ which takes this $7$-dimensional cross-product into the standard one, related to the octonions. Thus the stabilizer of this cross-product is conjugate to the compact $G_2$ inside $GL(7,\mathbb{R})$, via $g$, and is thus isomorphic to the compact $G_2$.

Comment: you mean it's isomorphic to the compact G_2, right?

Comment: right. I meant the compact $G_2$.